# how to wait http response in observable (rxjs)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

This is the original code.

```
// info.service.ts.  

  this.info$ = new BehaviorSubject<Info>(null);

  async getInfo() {
    try {
      const info = await this.infoApi.getInfo();
      console.log(info) // info {name: 'sdf', 'age': 12}
      this.info$.next(info);
    } catch {
      this.info$.next(null);
    }
  }



  // infoApi Class
  getInfo() {
    return this.apiService.get<Info>(`/info`, this.infoService....);
  }
```

For asynchronous processing using rxjs, we modified the code as follows.  Other asynchronous processing codes in my project have also been modified to rxjs in the following way, and they are working fine. However, only the getinfo service does not work properly. Asynchronous processing is not progressing properly.
As a result of checking the network panel, the info data request is checked in the managed state. Please let me know if there are any expected problems.
(Async, wait is not available, so I'm trying to use Rxjs. )

Both versions of code do not work as expected.

first version

```
// info.service.ts
  getInfo() {
    from(this.infoApi.getInfo()).subscribe(
      info => {this.info$.next(info); 
      console.log(info) // null
      error => {this.info$.next(error)
      }
    )
  }

  // infoApi Class
  getInfo() {
    return this.apiService.get<Info>(`/info`, this.infoService....);
  }

// api.service.ts
  get<T>(url: string, opts?: options) {
    return this.request<T>('GET', url, null, opts);
  }
```

second version

```
// info.service.ts
  getInfo() {
   this.infoApi.getInfo().subscribe(
      info => {this.info$.next(info); 
      console.log(info) // null
      error => {this.info$.next(error)
      }
    )
  }

  // infoApi Class
  getInfo() {
    return from(this.apiService.get<Info>(`/info`, this.infoService....);
  }

// api.service.ts
  get<T>(url: string, opts?: options) {
    return this.request<T>('GET', url, null, opts);
  }
```

Comment: It looks like fine, what does the error look like?

Comment: The data received in the http response is null. The other code works differently from the existing code even though there is no change. I don't know why @Pylon

Comment: It's strange. Could you show us the code of this.apiService.get() method? I want make sure we can covert the result of this method to an Observable.

Comment: what does apiService return? have you changed it too to return an observable?

Comment: The api service is not available. However, the asynchronous code elsewhere using the same API service has switched in this way and works fine. And the same error occurs even if you change the infoAPi class to return observable as follows.


getInfo() {
    return from(this.apiService.get<Info>(`/info`, this.apiService...));
}


It's just api of code.
// api.service.ts
  get<T>(url: string, opts?: options) {
    return this.request<T>('GET', url, null, opts);
  }


@Pylon @Fateh Mohamed

Answer (score 0):

The getInfo() returns an Observable, there is no need to use from() in your  info.servive.ts.

Also the formatting in the subscribe section could be:

```
  getInfo() {
    this.infoApi.getInfo()
    .subscribe({
      next: (info => {this.info$.next(info); 
      console.log(info)}), // null
      error: (error => this.info$.next(error))
      }
    )
  }
```

I've constructed a little example using randomAPI

info.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Using random data api for example
export type Info = {
  blend_name: string;
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class infoApiService {
  info$: BehaviorSubject<Info> = new BehaviorSubject<Info>(null);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // Use subscription for making BehaviorSubject work...
    this.getInfo().subscribe()
  }

  getInfo() {
    return this.http
      .get<Info>('https://random-data-api.com/api/coffee/random_coffee')
      .pipe(
        tap({
          next: (info) => {
            this.info$.next(info);
            console.log('logging in tap', info);
          },
          error: (error) => this.info$.error(error),
        })
      );
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Info, infoApiService } from './info.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  infoObs$!: Observable<Info>;

  constructor(private info: infoApiService) {
    this.infoObs$ = this.info.info$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="infoObs$ | async">
  <h3>The info is here : {{ (infoObs$ | async).blend_name }}</h3>
</div>
```

It's available in StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wgjsfa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Finfo.service.ts

Comment: I tried this code too, but it doesn't work properly.... I really don't know why @Charlie V

Comment: The endpoint works correctly when using Postman or directly? Does the network tab in de developer tools show a correct call to the endpoint?

Comment: yes i checked..... @Charile V